# Select all columns except 1 column with condition 1 and the remaning column with condition 2 in SQL

Tags: sql, columnsorting

I have this table named pricelist:

```
ProductID      Month      Price   Quantity   Bad_debt
123            202201     100     15         12
446            202201     392     72         5
285            202201     721     10         29
108            202201     903     6          33
792            202110     827     22         1
612            202110     448     3          0
```

I want to have the output table that returns: ProductID, Month, Revenue (Price*Quantity), Bad_debt of all products in "202201" (for ProductID "108", the revenue should be 0).
e.g.,

```
ProductID      Month      Revenue    Bad_debt
123            202201     1500       12
446            202201     28224      5
285            202201     7210       29
108            202201     0          33
```

I'm new to SQL, so may I ask, what should be the SQL query for this?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: Sample data is fine, but also _specify_ the expected result.

Comment: Thanks, I just edited my question with the expected result

Comment: @khuetran Why `for ProductID "108", the revenue should be 0`? Which condition leads to this?

Comment: `SELECT ProductID, Month, (Price*Quantity) as Revenue    Bad_debt FROM pricelist WHERE Month = 202201   UNION 
(SELECT ProductID, Month, 0 as Revenue    Bad_debt FROM pricelist WHERE Month = 202201 and ProductID = 108`

Comment: because I dont want to take the revenue's figure of ProductID 108, but still keep its bad_debt, so the only solution coming to my mind is to set its revenue to 0

Comment: Hardcoding id values in SQL queries is usually a bad idea, and a maintenance nightmare.

Comment: Instead you need to describe the reason you don't want 108. (So similar cases will be handled the same.)